# Passing child components vs passing plain js object

Tags: reactjs

What is the preferred approach for passing static list of items into component?

Let's say for example that I have an `Options` component which should render as a dropdown with multiple `OptionsItem`.

Is it better to create `Options` component to be used this way

```
<Options>
  <OptionsItem>Option 1</OptionsItem>
  <OptionsItem>Option 2</OptionsItem>
  ...
</Options>
```

or this way

```
<Options items=['Option 1', 'Option 2', ...] />
```

and have something like this inside `render` method

```
items.map((item, index) => <OptionsItem>item</OptionsItem>)
```

I pass an array of simple strings for simplicity but it could be an object or array of objects as well

I like the first approach more, I think it's easier to read and is more flexible. Another advantage is that I don't have to think of a unique key while rendering items (and using index is usually not a good idea), the only 'disadvantage' I see is that it requires a little bit more code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess both are valid.
If you have 2000 options I think you should take the second one... But else first one feels more readable.

The first one is closer to some react native component (that could be consider to be a React standard ?) :

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker.html

```
<Picker
  selectedValue={this.state.language}
  onValueChange={(lang) => this.setState({language: lang})}>
  <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
  <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
</Picker>
```

Best way is maybe :

```
<Options>
    <Options.Item />
</Options>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually support either an array of primitives or React elements. Using [React.Children.map](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children.map) to convert each child to an OptionsItem if it isn't a React element. You could further restrict the propType to be either an OptionsItem or a string (or number or whatever) if you needed to.

```js
const OptionItem = (props) => (
  <div> {props.children} </div>
);

const Options = (props) => {
  const children = React.Children.map(props.children, (child) => {
    if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
      return child;
    } else {
      return <OptionItem>{child}</OptionItem >
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className="options">
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

Options.propTypes = {
  children: React.PropTypes.node
}

ReactDOM.render(
 <Options>
     {['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth']}
    </Options > ,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```